# форма поиска что ей не так

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно ,чтобы лупа была по правому боку. Первоначально все стояло на месте, а теперь развалилось. Ошибку найти не могу.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
form {
  position: relative;  
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.search {
    width: 675px; /* Ширина поля с кнопкой */
    border: 1px solid #8d9e7a; /* Параметры рамки */
    border-radius: 5px;
    min-height: 20px; /* Минимальная высота */
    padding: 18px 30px 17px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px #9ea792;
}
   }
   input[type="search"] {       
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-size: 3.36пт;
    line-height: 7.2пт;
    color: #90a4ae;
    border: none; /* Убираем рамку */
    outline: none; /* Убираем свечение в Chrome и Safari */
   -webkit-appearance: none; /* Убираем рамку в Chrome и Safari */
    vertical-align: middle; /* Выравнивание по середине */
    
   }    

  input [type="submit"] {  
  color: #9aa38c;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 20px; /* Ширина кнопки */
  height: 20px; /* Высота кнопки */
  border: none;     /* Убираем рамку */
  font-family: FontAwesome;*/
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title> 
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/solid.css" integrity="sha384-v2Tw72dyUXeU3y4aM2Y0tBJQkGfplr39mxZqlTBDUZAb9BGoC40+rdFCG0m10lXk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/fontawesome.css" integrity="sha384-q3jl8XQu1OpdLgGFvNRnPdj5VIlCvgsDQTQB6owSOHWlAurxul7f+JpUOVdAiJ5P" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
   <form>
       <div class="search">
         <input type="search" placeholder = "Search Your Keywords . . .">
         <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       </div>
    </form>
  </div>
 </div>      
</body>
```

Comment: При воспроизведении вашего примера, она справа (не понятно).

Comment: Моя вам рекомендация, `чтоб ошибок на начальном этапе было меньше - комментируйте каждый шаг (каждый!!!).` Да это возможно лишняя работа, но эти действия избавят вас от подобных ситуаций и внесут понимание в ваш код, как с вашей стороны, так и других разработчиков (все равно при минификации комментарии все уберутся). Та же история с JS, но там кроме комментариев рекомендую проверять все через `console.log();`.

Comment: может через отладчик все-таки а не через `console.log();`?

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить иконке свойство `float: right` или сделать тоже самое, но на flex.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*Icon wrapper*/
.icon-wrap {
  float: right;
}


form {
  position: relative;  
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.search {
    width: 675px; /* Ширина поля с кнопкой */
    border: 1px solid #8d9e7a; /* Параметры рамки */
    border-radius: 5px;
    min-height: 20px; /* Минимальная высота */
    padding: 18px 30px 17px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px #9ea792;
}
   }
   input[type="search"] {       
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-size: 3.36пт;
    line-height: 7.2пт;
    color: #90a4ae;
    border: none; /* Убираем рамку */
    outline: none; /* Убираем свечение в Chrome и Safari */
   -webkit-appearance: none; /* Убираем рамку в Chrome и Safari */
    vertical-align: middle; /* Выравнивание по середине */
    
   }    

  input [type="submit"] {  
  color: #9aa38c;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 20px; /* Ширина кнопки */
  height: 20px; /* Высота кнопки */
  border: none;     /* Убираем рамку */
  font-family: FontAwesome;*/
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title> 
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/solid.css" integrity="sha384-v2Tw72dyUXeU3y4aM2Y0tBJQkGfplr39mxZqlTBDUZAb9BGoC40+rdFCG0m10lXk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/fontawesome.css" integrity="sha384-q3jl8XQu1OpdLgGFvNRnPdj5VIlCvgsDQTQB6owSOHWlAurxul7f+JpUOVdAiJ5P" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
   <form>
       <div class="search">
         <input type="search" placeholder = "Search Your Keywords . . .">
         <span class="icon-wrap"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
       </div>
    </form>
  </div>
 </div>      
</body>
```